# how to use pointers to functions?

Tags: c, function-pointers

for exp : this program isn't working to me..
can anyone explian to me how to use correctly a way to use in this program pointers to functions
the program gives me runtime error

the program should be generic and returns the size of any given array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int ReturnSize_INT(void *a)
{
    a = (int*)a;
    int count  = 0 ;
    int *p = (int*)a;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}
int ReturnSize_char(void *a)
{
    a = (char*)a;
    int count  = 0 ;
    char *p = (char*)a;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}
int ReturnSize_float(void *a)
{
    a = (int*)a;
    int count  = 0 ;
    float *p = (float*)a;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{

    int a [] = {1,2,5,7,8};
    char b[]={'a','b','c','\0'};
    float c [] = {2.75,5.25,7.27,4.25};
    int (*ReturnSize)(void *e);
    ReturnSize = ReturnSize_INT;
    printf("%d",ReturnSize(&a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Compile error? Runtime problem?

Comment: `a = (int*)a;` - what? why? `while(p != NULL)` -- `p` is never `NULL` unless it overflows... what are you even doing with this code?

Comment: a = (int*) a - suppose to turn a into a int* pointer no?

Comment: if p can never reaches null then what is the end of the array 0?

Comment: gives me run time error

Comment: There is no way to find the size of an array in C. You have to keep track of it manually. Alternatively, you could use a sentinel value to denote the final element like strings do.

Comment: @user3253375 Since `a` is declared as a pointer to `void`, it will never become a pointer to `int`. Anyway, you don't need an explicit cast to make an `int *` out of a `void *`. This works: `int *b = a;`

Comment: Don't assume that because you have added `\0` on the end of you char *s you can do likewise with other data types

Answer (score 2):

Pass `a` to the function - not `&a`. The name of the array is a pointer to the start of the array.

```
printf("%d",ReturnSize(a));
```

Secondly, there are no terminators in the data arrays. You could use a nominal value such as -1 for example. Note that the pointer p is derefenced (`*p`) to get the value p points to:

```
int a [] = {1,2,5,7,8,-1};  // in main

int ReturnSize_INT(void *a)
{
    a = (int*)a;
    int count  = 0 ;
    int *p = (int*)a;
    while(*p != -1)
    {
        count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}
```